# Синтаксический разбор СБП

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксический-разбор, бсп

Правильно ли я делаю синтаксический разбор предложения: "Моросил дождь, волжская вода помутнела"?

(Болд – это сказуемое, курсив – подлежащее)

1. **Моросил** (глаг.) *дождь* (сущ.), волжская (прил.) *вода* (сущ.) **помутнела** (глаг.). (повествовательное, невосклицательное, сложное, бессоюзное.)
2. Дальше построить схему.

   Между частями СБП ставится запятая, т. к. перечисляются события, которые происходят одновременно.

Заранее большое спасибо за ответ! :)

Comment: Совсем не факт, что одновременно. Запятая из-за того, что две грамматические основы.

Comment: @oleedd, это БСП, в таких предложениях не обязательно запятая, может быть двоеточие или тире. Запятая ставится только, если пречисление событий, которые происходят одновременно или последовательно

Comment: А сам алгаритм синтаксческого разбора правильный? Может каких-то пунктов не хватает? :)

Comment: Это обычно так. *Сегодня дождь, завтра снег, позавчера был ливень.* Здесь нет последовательности. Так что время и порядок действий лучше не учитывать. Может, и не хватает. Надо делать по схеме. Здесь люди таким не занимаются, ведь это только в школе нужно.

Comment: @oleedd как же тут не учитывать порядок. "Моросил дождь, волжская вода помутнела". Мне кажется, тут очевидно, что вода помутнела из-за дождя.

Comment: @Nektoid Не учитывать в общем, не именно здесь. Последовательность не требуется для постановки запятой между частями БСП. А что, дождь грязный, что вода стала мутной? Какая связь? Если из-за дождя, необходимо тире (потому что следствие).

Comment: @oleedd вот другой пример: "Я вышел из квартиры, запер дверь, спустился по лестнице". Никаких тире, никаких вытеканий одного из другого, но события идут именно в таком порядке и поменяны местами быть не могут.

Comment: @Nektoid Но не всегда же так, когда запятая. А если не всегда, то это не критерий.

Comment: @oleedd ну, если "не всегда" не критерий, то у того же Розенталя критериев раз-два и обчёлся, потому что у него едва ли не в каждом правиле присутствует оговорка "обычно", а то и список исключений :)

Comment: @Nektoid Вы так и не сказали про связь между дождём и мутной водой. Дождь состоит из испарённой воды, а грязь не испаряется. "Обычно" — это страховка. Ни один человек не может знать обо всём, что может существовать в языке, особенно в русском. Поэтому нельзя быть категоричным. Критерии должны всегда работать, иначе это показатель, а он может и подвести. Критерий такой: между простыми предложениями нет никаких взаимосвязей (следствие, причина, вывод, пояснение, раскрытие содержания и т.п.) либо же нет цели их показать (но порой так нельзя).

Comment: @oleedd не знаю, почему так происходит, но как человек, живущий в городе на Волге, подтверждаю: в дождь вода в этой реке мутнеет. Может быть, песок с берегов утаскивается. Может быть, со дна поднимается какими-то вихревыми потоками воды. Не интересовался.